# Logical error on a bubble sorting method the comparing two objects in a array

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I am trying to complete a bubble sort but I am getting this logical error:

```
Width: 3.2  height: 2.5 length: 9.1 Volume: 72.8
Width: 5.0  height: 4.8 length: 2.5 Volume: 60.0
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 20.5 height: 4.5 length: 80.75   Volume: 7449.1875
Width: 15.5 height: 44.2    length: 20.3    Volume: 13907.53
Width: 1.0  height: 1.0 length: 1.0 Volume: 1.0
Width: 14.23    height: 7.45    length: 10.5    Volume: 1113.14175
Width: 6.0  height: 5.0 length: 10.2    Volume: 306.0
Width: 7.5  height: 7.5 length: 7.5 Volume: 421.875
Width: 101.2    height: 32.5    length: 105.0   Volume: 345345.0
```

The bubble shorting is supposed put the volume lowest to highest using a compareTo method.
I do not know what I am doing wrong, here is my method I tried.

```
static void bubbleSort(Box[] theBoxes) { 
    int n = theBoxes.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ ){
        if(theBoxes[i].compareTo(theBoxes[i+1] ) > 0){
          Box temp = theBoxes[i];
          theBoxes[i] = theBoxes[i+1];
          theBoxes[i + 1] = temp;
        }else if(theBoxes[i].compareTo(theBoxes[i+1] ) < -1){
          Box temp = theBoxes[i+1];
          theBoxes[i+1] = theBoxes[i];
          theBoxes[i] = temp;
       }
    } 
  }
```

Here is the box class

```
public class Box {
  private double width, height, length;
  
  Box(double w, double h, double l){
    width=w;
    height=h;
    length=l;
  }
  
  private double getVolume(){
    return width*height*length;
  }
    
  public int compareTo(Box o){
    double myVol = this.getVolume();
    double thatVol = o.getVolume();
    if (myVol>thatVol)
      return 1;
    else if (myVol<thatVol)
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
    return "Width: "+width+
           "\theight: "+height+
            "\tlength: "+length+
            "\tVolume: "+getVolume();
  }

          
}
```

I cannot change the class at all, the only thing I can change is the actual bubble sorting, thank you.

Comment: Your code makes only one pass over the input.  That's not how a bubble sort works.  Please review the bubble sort algorithm and modify your code to match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 static void bubbleSort(Box[] theBoxes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theBoxes.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < theBoxes.length - 1; j++) {
        if (theBoxes[j].compareTo(theBoxes[j + 1]) > 0) {
          Box temp = theBoxes[j];
          theBoxes[j] = theBoxes[j + 1];
          theBoxes[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please don't do other people's homework for them. That is contrary to the spirit of the site.